# How does Dumbledore apparate into Hogwarts grounds in the sixth film?

Tags: harry-potter, movie

I know the films aren't canon, but it's stated quite often (in Hogwarts A History) that one cannot apparate in and out of Hogwarts.

So how can Dumbledore do it in the film?

Comment: @Edlothiad I know we have a long-running site policy of answers make dupes (which I had vaguely thought had been somewhat relaxed recently but maybe not), but even with that policy in mind, I still think the answers to the questions are quite different. The state of Hogwarts and its security was very different in *Deathly Hallows* and even more different during the battle. What's more the accepted answer to that question seems to say "maybe somebody else (who isn't even Dumbledore) allowed Draco" where as the answer to this question is "Dumbledore allowed himself"

Comment: I know the hard version of answers make dupes has been extended as far as saying if the answer to a new question can be found in an existing answer to an existing question, the new question is a dupe, but there are plenty of questions on this site which happen to use the same supporting evidence to answer quite different questions with quite different answers

Comment: If I could, @Au101, I would dupe this question to the half dozen questions about apparating into Hogwarts. But I can’t do I chose the one that seemed the most relevant, which also discussed dropping the jinx during the window. There is a general question along the lines of “what are the rules to apparating into Hogwarts?” OWTTE, and the answers should be in that general question, not 1 question made for each specific occurrence. That being said widening the “net” of dupe links can be good and is suggested practice by Shog9 so this is what I’ve done.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the film, Dumbledore specifically states, when Harry queries him,

> **Dumbledore:** Take my arm.
>
> **Harry:** Sir, I thought you couldn't Apparate within Hogwarts?
>
> **Dumbledore:** Well, being me has its privileges.

This is not actually *too* out of line with book canon where:

> 'As you may know, it is usually impossible to Apparate or Disapparate within Hogwarts. The Headmaster has lifted this enchantment, purely within the Great Hall, for one hour, so as to enable you to practise. May I emphasise that you will not be able to Apparate outside the walls of this Hall, and that you would be unwise to try.'
>
> *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince* - p.359 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 18, *Birthday Surprises*

However I agree that in the movies it seems like Dumbledore has the ability to Apparate or Disapparate at will from anywhere in Hogwarts, an ability that nobody else would have, even if they attempted it from the same place as Dumbledore. I, too, always took this little scene as an enormous slap in the face and I don't think that the movies and the books accord. I think that in the movies, Dumbledore, as Headmaster, has special privileges no-one else has. In the books, I think that Dumbledore placed many of the protective enchantments on Hogwarts and can lift many of them - including the ones concerning Apparition. But, when he lifts them, he lifts them for everyone in a defined area. He also does not appear to enable Apparition from *outside* Hogwarts. You can Apparate from one place within the Great Hall to another place within the Great Hall. That's it. Nevertheless, Dumbledore does have control over these enchantments in the books, so the movies, as I say, aren't *too* heretical.

Comment: Is there any evidence that Dumbledore has personally placed those enchantments, and can therefore lift them? I always concluded that his ability to lift the enchantments in the Great Hall (which appeared to be an annual thing, for each year's Apparition lessons) and his ability to bypass the restriction on Appiration all together were a function of his being Headmaster, not merely in the administrative sense, but as being recognized as such by the castle itself; compare Umbridge, who was appointed Headmistress by the Ministry of Magic, but the castle refused to recognize her as such.

Comment: @sharur I think regarding the Apparition enchantments specifically they were probably not put there by Dumbledore, nor was the ability to remove them probably unique to Dumbledore. However, I was thinking about the additional enchantments that he *did* place and which, in book canon, we explicitly see him removing

Comment: "As they flew over the dark, twisting lane down which they had walked earlier, Harry heard, over the whistling of the night air in his ears, Dumbledore muttering in some strange language again. He thought he understood why as he felt his broom shudder for a moment when they flew over the boundary wall into the grounds: **Dumbledore was undoing the enchantments he himself had set around the castle, so that they could enter at speed.**" (*Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince* - p.544 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 27, *The Lightning-Struck Tower*)